# Default mode parameters affecting ACL permissions

Tags: permissions, access-control-list, chmod

I have just started working as sysadmin and encountered my first problem.

What I am trying to do is set permissions of a directory so that all the subdirectories and files in the directory AND newly created files can be used only by groups and users I let.

I have come this far:

```
setfacl -Rdm m::rwx mydir
setfacl -Rdm o::--- mydir
setfacl -Rdm g:everybody:rwx
```

I also set all those permissions without -d flag. In my understanding, the default mask determines the upper bound of permissions.

I expected that when a user belonging to group *everybody* creates new file:

```
touch mydir/newfile
```

that permissions on that file are *rwx*. However, they are *rw-*. I found out that if a default ACL exists (which it does), the permission bits assigned to the new object correspond to the overlapping portion of the permissions of the **mode parameter and** those that are defined in the **default ACL**.

I assume that mode parameters are interfering with my permissions, but I have not found a way to change that. 
I tried:

```
chmod a+rwx mydir
```

(and few modifications) and it didn't work.

So I guess the question is: how do I change default mode parameters so that they do not affect permissions set with ACL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `touch` command does **not** set the executable bit. This means than whatever default ACL you assign to the directory, the touched file will **not** have the executable bit set.

This does not depend on ACLs: for example, think about the `umask` command, which operate on basic POSIX permissions. While you can set `umask` to not filter any permissions (and indeed root has all permissions enabled, by default), `touch` will **not** create an executable file.